# WCF Services Rest Call

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, automapper

I have a WCF Service callable in SOAP and REST. 
If a make SOAP call this works properly, but with REST I have problems.

In summary, the method return POCO ENTITY, but when I call I get a connection error canceled.
The same thing not happens if I call another method that returns a boolean or a string (ie native types).

The error seemed to me that POCO entity that I'm using was not really (that's what I'm using Devart so pretty sure it is). 
So what I did, I created a custom map of it (with same property) and i have used AutoMapper to do mapping.

The problem is still there :-(

This is the .svc.cs

```
 public List<GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO> GetLuoghiSimiliByAddress(string toponimo, string nomestrada, string civico, int idcomune)
    {
        Agile.SL.Services.IAnagraficaService srv = new Agile.SL.Services.Impl.AnagraficaService();
        List<GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO> result = new List<GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DTOGetLuoghiSimiliByAddress, GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO>();
        foreach (var dto in srv.GetLuoghiSimiliByAddress(toponimo, nomestrada, civico, idcomune).ToList<DTOGetLuoghiSimiliByAddress>())
        {
            GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO newdto = Mapper.Map<DTOGetLuoghiSimiliByAddress, GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO>(dto);
            result.Add(newdto);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

result contains properly my list of objects.

This is svc

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetLuoghiSimiliByAddress?Toponimo={toponimo}&Nome_Strada={nomestrada}&Civico={civico}&Id_Comune={idcomune}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO> GetLuoghiSimiliByAddress(string toponimo, string nomestrada, string civico, int idcomune);
```

Work properly with this method and operation contract

```
    public bool IsUserAlreadyRegistered(string email)
    {
        Agile.SL.Services.IAnagraficaService srv = new Agile.SL.Services.Impl.AnagraficaService();
        return srv.CheckEmailExistance(email);
    }            

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "IsUserAlreadyRegistered?Email={email}",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
bool IsUserAlreadyRegistered(string email);
```

this is GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace Merqurio.Agile.DL.Model.Entities
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [Serializable]
    public class GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO
    {

        private int _Id_Luogo;
        private string _Toponimo;
        private string _Nome_Strada;
        private string _Civico;


        public GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO()
        {

        }


    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Id_Luogo in the schema.
    /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Order=1)]
        public int Id_Luogo
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Id_Luogo;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._Id_Luogo != value)
                {
                    this._Id_Luogo = value;
                }
            }
        }


    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Toponimo in the schema.
    /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Order=2)]
        public string Toponimo
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Toponimo;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._Toponimo != value)
                {
                    this._Toponimo = value;
                }
            }
        }


    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Nome_Strada in the schema.
    /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Order=3)]
        public string Nome_Strada
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Nome_Strada;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._Nome_Strada != value)
                {

                    this._Nome_Strada = value;

                }
            }
        }


    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Civico in the schema.
    /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Order=4)]
        public string Civico
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Civico;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._Civico != value)
                {

                    this._Civico = value;

                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Could you show GetLuoghiSimiliByAddressesDTO code ?

Comment: yes i have done! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "IsReference = true" on your DataContract.

From MSDN :

> Use the IsReference property to instruct the DataContractSerializer to
>   insert XML constructs that preserve object reference information.

You are returning JSON, not XML...

Anyways you don't need it here, I don't see any circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error code you get back when you make the REST call. Also try to enable tracing on your service to see why the request fails via REST. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://rajeshsv.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-enable-tracing-in-wcf.html)

Also try to use fiddler to inspect your request that is being made to your service.